# using js to login user that's already stored in firebase db

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication

I created a user inside my firebase DB and wanna use javascript to log in to that user then redirect him to admin.html page I created, i use bootstrap and jquery and they work fine i guess

now this is my index.html home page that contains the login form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
              crossorigin="anonymous"/>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
                integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
                crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
        <! to connect firebase to our project -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase.js"></script>
    </head>

    <! these values of each class="" are coming from bootstrap -->
    <body class="bg-dark">

        <div id="login-card" class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h1>Wallpaper App Admin</h1>
                <form id="login-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!====================================================
                        this label is related to the email input under it
                        cause the value of for="" is the id of the email input
                        ===================================================-->
                        <label for="email">email</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="passsword">passsword</label>
                        <input type="passsword" id="passsword" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button id="btn-login" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <! link the javascript files that are inside js folder with this page -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script>
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
                if (user) {
                    // user is logged in
                    window.location.href = "admin.html";
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

and this is the admin.html that I wanna go to after the login process done

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
              crossorigin="anonymous"/>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
                integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
                crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
        <! to connect firebase to our project -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h1>Hey you are logged in!</h1>
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>
      <script>
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
                if (!user) {
                    // user is not logged in
                    window.location.href = "index.html";
                }
            });
        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

but once I click on the login button I get this message:

> It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS
>   SDK. When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to
>   only import the individual SDK components you intend to use.
>
> For the CDN builds, these are available in the following manner
>   (replace  with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database,
>   etc):
>
> https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-.js

I tried everything, changed the firebase version inside the link to 5.0.0 instead of 5.5.6 and same problem occurs

also another error appears and says that the second parametar of the signInWithEmailAndPassword should be valid valid string even when I changed it so many times and the problem still the same

note: I follow some tutorial on youtube, I am totally new to this so please guide me

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that error is only a warning - it's telling you to not include all of Firebase:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase.js"></script>
```

Just use what you need like Core, Auth, ect.

Secondly, when you click the button to log the user in, you need to call the LogInUser function from Firebase. I don't see that in your code, are you using just a regular password/username? It would be something like:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(*TEXTEMAIL*, *TEXTPASSWORD*).then(function() {
// Userlogin. 

}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
});
```

You could also add a `.onSuccess()` function so when they officially log in, you can call your `admin.html`.

Comment: there wasn't any log in function in the video i followed and it worked with the instructor, but anyway it works now, i found out that I had a typo in the id "password" it was "passsword" and i felt like i wanna slap my face.

thanks for your responce anyway :)

Comment: Glad you figured it out!